# In references to dates on tombstones, יום שבת קודש or יום שבת?

Tags: words, hebrew, cemetery-grave, gravestone-inscription

Which is better, more correct, or necessary?

In references to dates on tombstones,

יום שבת קודש or יום שבת?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Shabbos Kodesh sounds more correct to me

Comment: Why ask in reference to graves? Why not ask in general which is the proper name for the day?

Comment: @DonielF, that's a very fair comment. However, I wanted to mention the context, as this may play a role. For example, in more informal contexts the outcome may be different, as opposed to a matzeva, which could be argued as formal and holy, and requires respect. This is my intuition, but I could be wrong.

Comment: I gather that there is a mitzvah to put a *matzevah* (tombstone). But, I'm not sure that there is any requirement to write anything at all on it. I know that sounds strange, but, I think that may be part of your premise in your question, that anything needs to be written. Thus, in a sense, does the tombstone have any "holiness" at all?

Comment: I disagree with the 2 VTC b/c of "Hebrew language". There may be a halachic angle to this question. Larry, you may want to edit your question incorporating what was in your response to DonielF.

Comment: @DanF, thanks for your feedback. I would tend to think that we couldn't really say there is no holiness. I honestly cannot quote the source off hand, but I'v heard repetitively that everything written has bearing in the upper worlds (akin to a eulogy). Thus, for example, we wouldn't think about writing anything incorrect.

Comment: To clarify; you're asking about writing the day of the week on which the deceased passed away?

Comment: SoI seem recall hearing that a death occurring on a specific Holy Day has special meaning.This references death on Ervev Shabbat [Link]: [http//: chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/617539/jewish/…]  If true, would that be a factor which form of 'Sabbath' is used? Sorry for the error in formatting the link.  – JJLL 5 mins ago

Answer (score 1):

To me, saying יום שבת קודש denotes a more religious meaning, whereas just saying יום שבת seems secular, because in modern Hebrew יום שבת simply means "Saturday." I'd go with יום שבת קודש.

Of course, this is one hundred percent opinion. Since this website is not intended for questions on Hebrew grammar, I assume you are looking for people's personal opinions with explanations.

Comment: "Since this website is not intended for questions on Hebrew grammar, I assume you are looking for people's personal opinions" Actually, just as the site isn't for grammar, it isn't for opinion based questions.

Comment: @mevaqesh - Agreed. But do you agree with me?

Comment: I agree that קודש means holy. Does tacking on an this adjective achieve anything? I don't know. While common in Hassidic literature and the like, classical Jewish literature didn't feel the need to hype everything up, like שבת קודש, and Torah hakedosha. (Not that they never used such terms). I think that like most other expressions, it is of little import, and anyone can use whichever they want.